# Question on Tensorflow Dense Layer Implementation

Tags: tensorflow

From https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense (*Note Section)

For an input of (batch_size, d0, d1) why is the same (d1, units) kernel used for every sub-tensor (1, 1, d1)?

Additionally, why is the higher dimension dense layer operation broken down to work on subsets of input nodes, instead of having a weight from all d0xd1 inputs to an output node?

I apologize if I am missing something obvious and thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I dug through the source code and found Tensorflow made a change in how they implement the dense operation and I asked my boss at uni why they made this change.

In tf1 for input > rank 2 they flattened the input and just did a regular 1-D dense operation.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.15/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py

In tf2 for input > rank 2 they use the tensordot operation. This uses a smaller kernel and shares it for all input sub-tensors. This has the effect of sharing the learned channel-wise information.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/ops/core.py